# On the solution of one matrix differential equation

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

We have the next equation 
$$\dot K=AK+KA^T+HH^T,$$
where $K(t),A(t),H \in R^{n \times n}, K-$is a symmetric matrix. How one can prove that the solution of this equation is as follows:
$$K(t)=\int_0^te^{As}HH^T e^{A^Ts}ds$$
on $ [0,t]$, provideed that $K(0)=\boldsymbol{0}$?

Comment: In the light of Harry49's answer, your formula is, in general, wrong:  It would be correct if you assumed $A$ to be **independent of time**, whereas you clearly wrote "$A(t)$".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a continuous-time *Lyapunov differential equation* (cf. [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2242471/418542) and references therein [[1]](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0910.1895.pdf)), which unique solution is given by
$$
K(t) = \int_0^t \Phi_{A^\top}^\top(t,s)\, H H^\top \Phi_{A^\top}(t,s) \,\text d s
$$
where $\Phi_{A^\top}$ is the transition matrix for the system $\dot X = A^\top X$, i.e., the matrix $\Phi_{A^\top}(t,s)$ solves
$$
\dot X(t) = A^\top(t)\, X(t), \qquad X(s) = I .
$$

---

[[1]](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0910.1895.pdf) J.M. Davis, I.A. Gravagne, R.J. Marks II, A.A. Ramos, "Algebraic and dynamic Lyapunov equations on time scales", In *42nd Southeastern Symposium on System Theory (SSST)*, 2010, arXiv:0910.1895v1

Comment: So the OP's formula is, in general, wrong:  see my comment above.